# : ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, function-pointers, function-templates-overloading

I am facing the error as in below,

```
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
void bcMwMrsh::cppListFromWire<CSSCODERec*>(void*&, RWTValSlist<CSSCODERec*, std::allocator<CSSCODERec*> >&, AISObject* (*)()) /app/sdasup/home/mhp/source/develop/sd/lib/libsdHostSupport.so
ld: fatal: symbol referencing error
```

Under bc/include/bcMwMrsh.h cppListFromWire defined as below, Please note I have declared and defined the cppListFromWire in .h

```
typedef AbcObject *(*factory)()

 namespace bcMwMrsh
 {

 template<typename listT>
 void cppListFromWire(void *&src,RWTValSlist<listT> &dest, factory);
 }

 template<typename listT>
 void bcMwMrsh::cppListFromWire(void *&src, RWTValSlist<listT> &list, factory factoryFunc)
 {LOG (LM_MARSHAL_COM, (" bcMwMrsh::cppAbcListFromWire()...\n"));
 int nItems = 0;
 ptrdiff_t* pstart = (ptrdiff_t*) src;
 bcMwMrsh::cppIntFromWire(src, &nItems);
 for (int i = 0; i < nItems; i++)
 {
 AbcObject *elem = factoryFunc();
 assert (elem); // improper assert; should cause exception - KD
 elem->fromWire(src);
 list.append(elem);
 }
 
 LOG (LM_MARSHAL_COM, (" bcMwMrsh::cppAbcListFromWire(): length %i\n", ptrdiff_t((ptrdiff_t*)src - pstart)));
 
 }
```

and under "wv/include/cppmarsh.h" cppListFromWire been defined as in below,

```
typedef AISObject *(*factorywv)();
namespace bcMwMrsh
{
 template<typename listT>
 void cppListFromWire(void *&src,RWTValSlist<listT> &dest, factorywv);
} 

 template<typename listT>
 void cppListFromWire(void *&src,RWTValSlist<listT> &list, factorywv factoryFunc)
 {
 LOG (LM_MARSHAL_COM, (" cppmarsh::cppListFromWire()...\n"));
 ptrdiff_t* pstart = (ptrdiff_t*) src;
 short nItems=0;
 bcMwMrsh::cppShortFromWire(src, &nItems);
 for (int i=0; i < nItems; i++)
 {
 AISObject *elem = factoryFunc();
 assert(elem); // improper assert; should cause exception - KD
 elem->fromWire(src, 0);
 list.append(elem);
 }
 
 LOG (LM_MARSHAL_COM, (" cppmarsh::cppListFromWire(): length %i\n", 
 ptrdiff_t((ptrdiff_t*)src - pstart)));
}
```

And the .so (/app/sdasup/home/mhp/source/develop/sd/lib/libsdHostSupport.so) path where the error is pointing out has cppListFromWire used at two files as in below,

under sd/sdHostSupport/csscode.cpp

```
#include "csscode.h"
#include "cppmarsh.h"

int CSSCODERecList::fromWire(void *&buf, long bufLen)
{
        bcMwMrsh::cppListFromWire(buf, contents, CSSCODERec::AISFactory);
        return 0;
}
```

and under sd/sdHostSupport/__cppmarsh.cpp

```
#include "cppmarsh.h"


void cppIntFromWire(void *&src, int *dest)
{
        assert(sizeof(int)==4);
        *dest=0;
#ifndef LITTLE_ENDIAN //NT Port
        *((char*)dest+3)=*((char*)src);
        *((char*)dest+2)=*((char*)src+1);
#else
        *((char*)dest)=*((char*)src);
        *((char*)dest+1)=*((char*)src+1);
#endif
        (char*&)src+=2;
}


template<typename listT>
void cppListFromWire(void *&src,RWTValSlist<listT> &list, factorywv factoryFunc)
{
  int nItems = 0;
  cppIntFromWire(src, &nItems);
  for (int i = 0; i < nItems; i++)
  {
    AISObject *elem = factoryFunc();
    assert(elem);                         // improper assert; should cause exception - KD
    elem->fromWire(src, 0);
    list.append(elem);
  }
}
```

Is this something related to function-overloading, as I can see cppListFromWire defined has one parameter with different return type? However I see that is falling under overloading rules. Anything that differs here please let me know.

I tried including signature in both the files didn't work. Also tried including absolute header paths didn't work. One thing that worked was when I commented out below line form the file sd/sdHostSupport/csscode.cpp but that vague thing one can do.

```
bcMwMrsh::cppListFromWire(buf, contents, CSSCODERec::AISFactory);
```

I am unable to figure out what's the problem and how to resolve that. Been stuck for about 2 weeks now. Any kind of help/suggestions/inputs are greatly appreciated.

Comment: you've missed the namespace in your definition of `cppListFromWire` in `cppmarsh.h`

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I have defined namespace.

Comment: You've declared your function in a namespace but the definition is not in that namespace so defines a new function in the global namespace

Comment: As far as I can see I have defined with in the namespace bcMwMrsh
{
 template<typename listT>
 void cppListFromWire(void *&src,RWTValSlist<listT> &dest, factorywv);
}   Please do point/ or mark if I have missed it.

Comment: no, that's the declaration, the definition is in the global namespace

Comment: Adding cppListFromWire definition with in the namespace is not working.

Comment: In the header or the cpp file? It needs to be in the header

Comment: I have defined in cppmarsh.h itself not in .cpp

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245070/discussion-between-puneeth-and-alan-birtles).